# Azure SQL Create new table from merging two others using a custom ID column

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

Im new to configuring Azure SQL but im trying to create a new table by merging some columns from two tables which both share the same Custom ID column.

For examples my data is like the following

| CustomID | InfoColumn1 | InfoColumn2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UNIQUEID001 | InfoColumnData123 | TEST10001afssf |
| UNIQUEID002 | InfoColumnData456 | TEST10001acetca |
| UNIQUEID003 | InfoColumnData789 | TEST10001bsgtse |

And

| CustomID | OtherColumn1 | OtherColumn2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UNIQUEID001 | Blah2142214asfasf | a4a545a545a |
| UNIQUEID002 | Blah436346sadsasf | aa45a4w555a5a |
| UNIQUEID003 | Blah43643373bsegags | asgsgsgsag |

And i want to create a table like the following

| CustomID | InfoColumn1 | OtherColumn1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UNIQUEID001 | InfoColumnData123 | Blah2142214asfasf |
| UNIQUEID002 | InfoColumnData456 | Blah436346sadsasf |
| UNIQUEID003 | InfoColumnData789 | Blah43643373bsegags |

Am i going about this the right way or do i have to create a PowerAutomate Flow? and use a condition of ID eq ID?

Also my data is quite large (40k unique IDs)

Comment: post the code what you have tried. what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: You can simply create a view in the database. Do not create a Power Automate flow. I don't see anything in your explanation that indicates you should do that.